# Database Upgrade 5.32 to 5.70.1 (Wordpress)

Tags: upgrade, database

I have upgraded the program from 5.32 to 5.70.1 on WordPress 6.4.3 but the database will not upgrade.

When I run the script(
http://russisforus.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1) it takes me to a login screen even though I am currently logged in as an Administrator.  When I log in it goes to the WP Dashboard, not an Upgrade Screen.

There are no errors in WP, or on my Server Logs.

Is there an SQL script I can run in phpmyadmin?

This may also be database related, but I can not access CIVICRM by clicking on CIVIVRM from the WP menu.  When I do that I get"
"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

I can get to CIVICRM by clicking on CIVICRM - Settings in the menu bar..

Comment: Do you have cv or wp-cli installed? You can do db upgrade from using command line

Comment: No.  Are those WP extensions?  I do not have server side access.

Comment: The issue was having the correct combination of both the HTTP/S and www in the URL used when Upgrading the Database.  Your use of the HTTPS protocol and www subdomain must exactly match the settings for your CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL in your civicrm.settings.php file.

It would be nice if that bit was included in the Upgrade Instructions at:
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

Comment: If you click the pencil icon at the top right of that page you can submit amendments.  It probably belongs in the installation instructions since that will cause you other issues if there is a mismatch - but no harm in mentioning in upgrade as well.